# Socket.io: How to handle function parameters properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, function-parameter

I'm trying to set socket parameter (nick) as follows

```
socket.on('something', function(who){
    socket.nick = who;
    //something
});
```

Following code returns undefined to the client, which is the issue here.

But when i do it like...

```
socket.on('something', function(who){
    socket.nick = 'who';
    //something
});
```

This returns 'who' to everyone, ofc.

Is there a way to get the upper code snippet working?

Comment: What is `who` (the variable)?  `console.log`?

Comment: who variable is passed from the client as "username"

Comment: No, I mean what does `console.log` say it is?

Comment: if i log in as "monkey" it gets it as it should. { x : 'monkey' } The problem might be in the 'disconnect' function where i try to call the property.

Comment: Then maybe you want to do `socket.nick = who.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets can't communicate JavaScript objects or anything that can't be stringified simply.  If `who` is an object as in `{x: "monkey"}`, you probably want to use `who.x` instead, which is a string:

```
socket.nick = who.x;
```

You could also stringify the object to JSON and then parse it on the client:

```
socket.nickJson = JSON.stringify(who);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the lightning fast aid of [Explosion pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) the problem got solved.

instead of...

```
socket.on('something', function(who){
    socket.nick = who;
    //something
});
```

it should be

```
socket.on('something', function(who){
    socket.nick = who.x;
    //something
});
```